# Hide teams in project list from user?

Tags: azure-devops

In VSTS I have a one large project that consists of many teams. Now when I want to invite external users to a team I don't want them to be able to navigate to the project root and view the whole list of teams in that project. Is there a permission for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't the related permission can control it in VSTS.

Comment: Do you know any way I can structure my project so I can hide the teams from external clients?

Comment: No way to hide teams, you may create a new team project for them to do work.